# Download images with requests by generated links

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

i am not able to download from JavaScript generated images and to store them on my local machine. The code below is not giving any errors but there are no images in my folder. I tried already in many ways. Here is one of them:

```
path = "http://my.site.com/page/oo?_b=9V2FG34519CV2N56SLK567943N25J82V"
os.makedirs('C:/Images', exist_ok=True)
print('Dowload images %s...' % path)
res = request.get(path)
res.raise_for_status()

imageFile = open(os.path.join('logos', os.path.basename(res)), 'wb')
for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
  imageFile.write(chunk)
imageFile.close()
```

i am trying since two days to solve this problem, so i would be gratefully if somebody can help me!

Comment: you're not using selenium, why've you tagged it then? you're using `requests`.

Comment: @Ashish Ranjan this is not my entire code. The path is generated by selenium. Like this: path = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//xpath")
path = (path.get_attribute('onclick')).encode('utf-8')

Comment: i understand that, but that isn't the part of the question, since it's working and you already have the link and you're using `requests` further to download it.

Comment: @Ashish Ranjan its correct! i have the link, but in my local machine inside my folder, there is no image. With this generated link i am able to put into the browser and i can see the image. But how can i download it?

Comment: is there any chance, you can post the url for testing?

Comment: @Ashish Ranjan of course hier is one of them:http://epub.hpo.hu/e-kutatas/aa?_p=A554F6BCDBCEA51EFF1E0E17E777F3AC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've got the image `url`, you can use `requests` and `shutil` to save the image to a given directory (working for me for the given `url`):

```
import shutil
import requests
import os

url = 'http://epub.hpo.hu/e-kutatas/aa?_p=A554F6BCDBCEA51EFF1E0E17E777F3AC'
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open(out_file_path, 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
```

Comment: thank you for your help. On windows is not working for me. I will try to run this script on linux and i will keep you posted.

Comment: it works on Windows and on Linux. But i get the same error. When i open the images it says: The image can not be open. Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x3c0x48)

Comment: in what editor are you opening the file, also have you used the correct file extension while saving?

Comment: looks like it's png, try running `file file_name.jpg` on the terminal, to check the file format

Comment: it works budy thank you so much. It was the wrong format!